# Im unable to get NgRx Data to trigger an API call

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

Im trying to set up NgRx Data with a service that overrides the EntityData getAll() function, so that i can call an API. but nothing happens when i call EntityService.getAll()

entity-metadata.ts : standard definition for the EntityMetadataMap where i defined one entity named PageLoadData

```
import { EntityMetadataMap } from '@ngrx/data';

export const entityMetadata : EntityMetadataMap = {
    PageLoadData: {
        entityDispatcherOptions: {
            optimisticUpdate: true
        }
    }
}
```

My AppModule.ts

```
import { AppResolver } from './app.resolver';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EntityDataModule, EntityDataService } from '@ngrx/data';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { TryAtHomeComponent } from './try-at-home/try-at-home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { DesignersComponent } from './designers/designers.component';
import { PolicyComponent } from './policy/policy.component';
import { HowItWorksComponent } from './how-it-works/how-it-works.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { GiftCardComponent } from './gift-card/gift-card.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { PageLoadDataDataService } from './services/page-load-data.service';
import { PageLoadDataEntityService } from './services/page-load-entity.service';
import { entityMetadata } from './entity-metadata';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    TryAtHomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    DesignersComponent,
    PolicyComponent,
    HowItWorksComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    GiftCardComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    EntityDataModule.forRoot({
      entityMetadata: entityMetadata
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production}),
  ],
  providers: [PageLoadDataDataService, AppResolver, PageLoadDataEntityService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 

  constructor(
    entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    pageLoadDataService : PageLoadDataDataService,
  ) {
    entityDataService.registerService('PageLoadData', pageLoadDataService); // <-- register it
  }

}
```

page-load-entity-service.ts : i followed NgRx Data's standard documentation and created a service like below:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { EntityCollectionServiceBase, EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory } from "@ngrx/data";
import {PageLoadData } from '../user/model/user.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PageLoadDataEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<PageLoadData> {
    constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
        super('PageLoadData', serviceElementsFactory)
    }
}
```

page-load-data.service.ts : created this service to override the getAll functionality of the DefaultDataService

```
import { PageLoadData } from './../user/model/user.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { DefaultDataService, HttpUrlGenerator, Logger } from "@ngrx/data";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PageLoadDataDataService extends DefaultDataService<PageLoadData> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrl : HttpUrlGenerator, logger: Logger) {
        super('PageLoadData' , http, httpUrl);
        logger.log('in PLD Data Service');
        //if i subscribe here to getAll api works fine the issue is somewhere else in the set up
    }
    getAll(): Observable<PageLoadData[]> {
        return this.http.get<PageLoadData[]>('https://staging-api.designer-24.com/page/home?storeId=1')
    }
}
```

app.resolver.ts : Im using a resolver to call the getAll when the EntityService is loading

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap, filter, first } from "rxjs/operators";
import { PageLoadDataEntityService } from './services/page-load-entity.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {
    constructor(private pageLoadService: PageLoadDataEntityService) {}
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> {
        return this.pageLoadService.loaded$.pipe(
            tap(loaded => {
                console.log(loaded)
                if(!loaded) {
                    console.log('calling get all');
                    this.pageLoadService.getAll();   
                }
            }),
            filter(loaded => !!loaded),
            first()
        )
    }
}
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppResolver } from './app.resolver';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    // loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: {
      pageLoadData: AppResolver
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

heres my app component:

```
import { PageLoadDataEntityService } from './services/page-load-entity.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User, PageLoadData, HomeData } from './user/model/user.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'd24-web';
  data$: Observable<PageLoadData[]>;
  constructor(private userEntity : PageLoadDataEntityService) {
    this.data$ = userEntity.entities$.pipe(
        map(data => {
          console.log(data);
          return data
        })
    );
  }
}
```

app component html

```
<span *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data" >{{data}}</span>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is the redux inspector:

[screenshot of redux events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwjS4.png)

No API call and no Error is triggered even if i try to subscribe from within the resolver. I don't understand why. But in the redux inspector the getAll is triggered but its gray. not sure what that means

github link is here: https://github.com/rmoubayed/ngrx-data-test-env if anyone would like to clone and try it.

Comment: Is there a way to add a route parameter to getAll in your setup?

Answer (score 30):

I found the solution to this mess. Everything in my setup is LEGAL and NOT wrongly implemented in any way.

As it turns out I needed to load the StoreModule & Effects BEFORE the EntityDataModule!

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // EntityDataModule.forRoot({ // removed it from here
    //   entityMetadata: entityMetadata
    // }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    EntityDataModule.forRoot({ // and put it here
      entityMetadata: entityMetadata
    }),
  ],
```

After that everything worked normally again! Literal NEEDLE in a HAYSTACK :)

Hope this helps anyone else who faces the same issue :D

Comment: You have got to be kidding me -.- Been searching for an hour and just moved my `EntityDataModule.forRoot()` down one line and it fixed it...

Comment: You surely saved me a day of migraine inducing debugging!  Thank you!

Comment: If I could I would give 10 votes up for that answer. 2 hours wasted